# CSS Two divs for Text, one master, one slave

Tags: html, css

I want to create two divs next to each other, one left, one right, and both will contain text.

The left one should take as much space as needed for its text to stay on one line.

The right one should take the remainder space, independently of how big it's text may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, and making little modifications I think that the following solves perfectly your problem. See also the snippet below.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="left">some text</div>
    <div class="right">This is a very big text which is supposed to behave as wanted</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="left">a bit longer one</div>
    <div class="right">And a long last line to make sure that everything is fine with no side effects</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

li div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.left {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.right {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cj6PR/71/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left_div">

  </div>
  <div id="right_div">

  </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#left_div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color:#EEE;
  text-align:center;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

#right_div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color:#f9f9f9;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

The space functionality you're looking for may be achieved with some Jquery plugin or even vanilla JS but I'm not quite sure I understood what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you looking for, but hope it helps you: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/1d2mnjkx/1/)

`HTML`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left_div">
    It's my text, It's my text, It's my text, It's my text, It's my text, It's my text, It's my text, It's my text, It's my text, It's my text
  </div>
  <div class="right_div">
    More, more, more text, More, more, more text, More, more, more text
  </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.left_div {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
.right_div {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}
```